# Extract book title from image

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have many comics and I would like to extract their title using a webcam. I have made the code below :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import Output


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))

        image = cv2.imread(img_name)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)        
        img = Image.fromarray(im)
        results = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang='fra+eng', output_type=Output.DICT)

        # loop over each of the individual text localizations
        for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
            # extract the bounding box coordinates of the text region from
            # the current result
            x = results["left"][i]
            y = results["top"][i]
            w = results["width"][i]
            h = results["height"][i]
            text = results["text"][i]
            conf = int(results["conf"][i])


            # filter out weak confidence text localizations
            if conf > 50:
                    # display the confidence and text to our terminal
                    print("Confidence: {}".format(conf))
                    print("Text: {}".format(text))
                    print("")
                    text = "".join([c if ord(c) < 128 else "" for c in text]).strip()
                    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        
        cv2.imshow("res", image)


        #####################################
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I press "SPACE", a photo of the title is taken and tesseract tries to extract some text. I did the tests below.

[image]

[image]

How is it possible to improve that please ?
(except to find in the book the title written with a good font :-) )

Cheers

Karim

Comment: what exactly do you want to improve?

Comment: The first image for example